# Get Alfresco sites I am a member of

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

Is there a way to get the list of Alfresco Share sites I am a member of? (from a remote application)

By "member" I mean: listed at https://example.com/share/page/site/thesite/site-members

Ideally a CMIS call would be the best, but I guess it is impossible, so another REST API is OK too.
It needs to be fast even when there are thousands of sites, so checking for each site one-by-one would not work.
An official API that will not disappear soon is preferred.
It should work on Alfresco 4.2 and later.

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you targetting? 4.x? 5.0? 5.1?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Sorry for the omission, I modified my question! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse-engineering the Alfresco Share dashboard led me to discover this JSON REST call:

https://example.com/share/proxy/alfresco/api/people/nicolas/sites?roles=user&size=100

You get something like this:

```
[
{
    "url": "\/alfresco\/s\/api\/sites\/superproject",
    "sitePreset": "site-dashboard",
    "shortName": "superproject",
    "title": "Super Project",
    "description": "A fabulous project",
    "node": "\/alfresco\/s\/api\/node\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/9dfb2426-bc2e-471e-8452-d4f6ea4b1cfa",
    "tagScope": "\/alfresco\/s\/api\/tagscopes\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/9dfb2426-bc2e-471e-8452-d4f6ea4b1cfa",
    "siteRole": "SiteCollaborator",
    "isPublic": true,
    "visibility": "PUBLIC"
}
        ,
{
    "url": "\/alfresco\/s\/api\/sites\/another",
    "sitePreset": "site-dashboard",
    "shortName": "another",
    "title": "Another Project",
    "description": "A less wonderful project",
    "node": "\/alfresco\/s\/api\/node\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/3859750c-8b3a-4736-b3e5-1ca1c2ff1cac",
    "tagScope": "\/alfresco\/s\/api\/tagscopes\/workspace\/SpacesStore\/3859750c-8b3a-4736-b3e5-1ca1c2ff1cac",
    "siteRole": "SiteManager",
    "isPublic": true,
    "visibility": "PUBLIC"
}
]
```

So it works for my Alfresco 4.2 test server, but the problem is I am not really sure how "official" it is. If not official it might disappear in the next Alfresco release.

I have also found http://sharextras.org/jsdoc/share/enterprise-4.0.0/symbols/Alfresco.SiteFinder.html#memberOfSites which seems to be exactly what I need, but it is part of the [Alfresco Share JavaScript API](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/references/API-JS-Share-intro.html) whose documentation seems to end at 4.0 so I am not sure it still exists in Alfresco 5.

Comment: Do you seeing any issues, while using this ? https://example.com/share/proxy/alfresco/api/people/nicolas/sites?roles=user&size=100

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan: it works for my Alfresco 4.2 test server, but the problem is I am not really sure how "official" it is. If not official it might disappear in the next Alfresco release.

Comment: The Rest API you're using is still present in community head git / trunk, so you should be fine for a while yet. There might well be a nicer supported API for this in 5.1 or 5.2, but since you're on 4.2 that's not much help...

Comment: @Gagravarr: I was just testing on 4.2 because I want to be compatible all the way back to 4.2, but I want to be compatible with all newer versions as well :-)

Comment: people/{username}/sites is part of the official REST API. You might be interested in the API Explorer: https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/people/getSiteMembership

Comment: It's also covered in the official docs: http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/pra/1/concepts/pra-people.html

Answer (score 0):

You can to use this to get the membership details for a user.

```
GET /alfresco/service/api/sites/{shortname}/memberships/{username}
```

it worked for me, you can even test it with `Postman` but do not forget the `authentification`.

you can find more in https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference

Comment: From the question: "*It needs to be fast even when there are thousands of sites, so checking for each site one-by-one would not work.*"

Comment: I think that there's a solution for this, i will update my answer

Comment: the solution is to use only the part with `sites/{shortname}` it will give sites details, in this case i will give a try and if worked for me update this answer

Comment: There are a million sites, I can't launch a million requests each with the `{shortname}` of a single site.